# Area of touching part of Sphere to the wall.

Tags: geometry, area, spheres, noneuclidean-geometry

I believe that it has a very simple explanation but one question stuck in my mind. What is the area between sphere and wall when it touches to it.

[image]

If it is zero, why it is not occurring in real life?

Comment: It is zero, although this has no bearing on real life. A sphere is a mathematical idealization, not a real-world object.

Comment: Because spheres in real life deform and are not perfect spheres to begin with.

Comment: So you mean, if we have perfectly shaped solid sphere ball, we will get zero area between wall and object...

Comment: Yes, but it's meaningless to talk about a perfectly spherical ball in the real world. Something made up of atoms won't be spherical, and if you zoom in far enough then the boundary isn't a meaningful distinction.

Comment: Thanks for a great explanation.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "sphere" you specify a mathematical construct.  The sphere is tangent to the wall and the area of contact is zero.  That presumes that the sphere is completely rigid.  For many purposes that is a good approximation, but all materials deform if a pressure is applied.  That deformation will force the thing you called a sphere to no longer be a sphere.  It will have a flat spot at the wall contact. Given the mass, radius, and elastic modulus of the "sphere" it is a reasonable mechanical engineering calculation to approximately find the deformation and the area of contact.